# Why does my do-while "do" line execute twice before "while"

Tags: php, do-while

When I execute the code below, the `do{}` line executes twice, leaving `$item` with `false` before doing the `while()` check. `$allItems` is an array of one object. Why is it executing twice? Shouldn't `$item` just pick up the popped member and proceed to check?

```
// $allItems is an array of one object
do {
    $item = array_pop($allItems);
} while (
    $item->getProductId() != $product->getId() || count($allItems) <= 0
);
```

Comment: $item has just one value?

Comment: If $allitems has one item, it will pop that item, leaving the count equal to 0. Your while says to keep popping while count is equal to 0, so it pops again - but allitems is empty. That fails. You get a null and you then try to use NULL->getProductID().

Comment: thanks. refactored to ` $item->getProductId() != $product->getId() && count($allItems) > 0` . Add it as an answer mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $allitems has one item, it will pop that item, leaving the count equal to 0. Your while says to keep popping while count is equal to 0, so it pops again - but allitems is empty. That fails. You get a null and you then try to use NULL->getProductID(). You need to change your comparison to:

```
$item->getProductId() != $product->getId() && count($allItems) > 0
```

That will do the pop while the $allitems still has items to pop.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove the equals sign from your while condition `count($allItems) <= 0`. Because you first have one item which will reduce the count to 0 after one iteration but this won't trigger your while so it does a second iteration.

Another possibility would be to switch over to a while loop so it will check the condition before executing your code.